# ERROR: No 'ink_lang' dependency found

Tags: ink

On master branch after merged [this](https://github.com/paritytech/ink/pull/1223) PR, I try to build example contract and got this error. Has anyone faced this issue?
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
cargo install cargo-contract --version 2.0.0-rc
```

The above command will install v2 of cargo contract. This includes ink v4 which has renamed the `ink_lang` module to `ink`. Thus using `cargo-contract` before v2 results in the `ink_lang` not found error. Other changes have also been made for ink v4, such as `ink_env` becoming `ink::env`, so you will need to make the corresponding changes throughout your contract. [Here's a link to the cargo-contract v2 release.](https://github.com/paritytech/cargo-contract/releases/tag/v2.0.0-rc) And [here's a link to ink v4's release, which lists the breaking changes.](https://github.com/paritytech/ink/releases)

Answer (score 2):

It's because of cargo-contract branch hasn't merged and which is in progress, you can view details [here](https://github.com/paritytech/ink/pull/1404#issuecomment-1253595858)

Answer (score 0):

This version of cargo-contract solved it for me:

`cargo install cargo-contract --version 2.0.0-beta`